# querying two tables in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

there is surely some way to get this done in a lot less lines of code.

databases isn't my strongest and I'm new to sequelize and node. The user id comes in as a parameter and I have to check if there is a user in the user table. If no user just send back no user otherwise check pics table to see if user has a pic. userid is forign key in pics table. if user doesn't have a pic i give them a default other wise i set their pic as the stored one in the database. I have it working but I know it can be written a lot better with less lines of code many using findAll and include but I cant get it. Any help appreciated. Here is the code that works..

```
users.findById(userId)
    .then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            res.render('error', {
                message: 'No user found with id of ' + userId,
                error: {
                    status: 404
                }
            });
        } else {
            pics.findOne({
                where: {
                    user_id: userId
                },
                attributes: ['profile_pic_filename']
            }).then(function (pic) {
                if (!pic) {
                    //if no pic give a default
                    profilepic = process.env.DEFAULT_PROFILE_PIC;
                } else {
                    profilepic = CDNPath + pic.profile_pic_filename;
                }

                res.render('user', {
                        profilePic: profilepic,
                        firstname: user['first_name'],
                        username: user['username'],
                        surname: user['surname'],
                        email: user['email']}
                );
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> there is surely some way to get this done in a lot less lines of code.

You can put it all on one line if you minify it :D !

*Joking aside ...*

`.findOne` function returns a *promise*.

Unlike callbacks, with promsies, if there is an error thrown it will be caught by the accomanying *catch* function. All you need to do is put the error in the catch and don't bother with first query.

```
pics.findOne({ where: { user_id: userId }, attributes: ['profile_pic_filename']})
    .then(pic => {
        var profilepic = process.env.DEFAULT_PROFILE_PIC;
        if (pic) profilepic = CDNPath + pic.profile_pic_filename;

        res.render('user', {
            profilePic: profilepic,
            firstname: user['first_name'],
            username: user['username'],
            surname: user['surname'],
            email: user['email']}
        );
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // test the error is what you were expecting.
        return res.render('error',
            { message: 'No user found with id of ' + userId, error: { status: 404 }});
    });
```

Comment: Reducing whitespace is not optimization in any sense and comes with cost in readability and maintenance (note: I am not the downvoter).

Comment: @Wtower: No worries. I answered too quickly. I fixed code (before you commented)  to use a catch which is what the OP wanted (i.e. one less database operation). However, the initial edits I made were purely to improve readbility. I use early returns and fat arrow functions all the time to reduce eye strain and thats based on good style recommendations.

Comment: That surely looks better Chris